# mktextfm fails when pdflatex is invoked by cgi-bin script under www-data (apache)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-metrics, kpathsea

I'm starting `pdflatex` from a shell-script invoked as cgi-bin application on Ubuntu (running under default `www-data` user) and from time to time I have the following kind of error preventing compiling:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm0700
mktextfm: mktexdir ./.texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a failed.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

./thebook.tex:330: Font T2A/cmr/m/n/7=larm0700 at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (T
FM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.330 10 м/с\textsuperscript{2}

./thebook.tex:330:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on thebook.log.
```

Inspection shows that an empty directory `.texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a` created in a working dir (in contrast with `mktexdir` message).

Running the same script with `sudo -u www-data` fixes the problem temporary: fonts are generated and then this particular document can be compiled from the cgi-bin script. But it does not provide stable result: as new fonts are needed, cgi-bin script stops working again.

The similar problems are discussed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119786/compiling-a-latex-document-from-php/26119943?noredirect=1#comment40937047_26119943), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240725/how-can-i-get-php-to-compile-a-latex-document-if-it-www-data-cant-get-access), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023113/how-do-i-compile-tex-file-from-a-php-script-how-do-i-set-sudoers), [here](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-February/034863.html), [here](http://kodomo.cmm.msu.su/trac/kodomo/ticket/236) (in Russian), [here](http://www.progsoc.uts.edu.au/lists/slug/2001/September/msg01972.html) and maybe somewhere else, but no clear solutions provided.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding

```
export HOME='/var/www'
```

to the shell-script just before the `pdflatex` command.